# How to modify this axios object so I can choose between various headers?

Tags: javascript, http-headers, axios

I currently have the following axios object

```
    import axios from 'axios';
import constants from '../constants.js';
import Cookies from 'js-cookie';

const API = axios.create({
  baseURL: `${constants.urlBackend}`,
  timeout: 10000,
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
});

API.interceptors.request.use(
  config => {
    var accesstoken = Cookies.get('accesstoken');

    if (accesstoken) {
      config.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${accesstoken}`;
    } else {
      delete API.defaults.headers.common.Authorization;
    }
    return config;
  },

  error => Promise.reject(error)
);

export default API;
```

Which I use like the following for example

```
API.get(constants.urlBackend + "/status/ftp/Server3")
        .then((response) => {
            if (response.status === 200) {
                this.setState({ sonServerThreeStatus: true });
            } else {
                this.setState({ sonServerThreeStatus: false });
            }
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            this.setState({ sonServerThreeStatus: false })
        });
```

Point is, all those requests I have used so far using that object , have application/json content headers, but Im facing a problem and its that there are some that require a

```
headers: {
                 'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8'
             }
```

So I dont know how to trigger between the various headers, or how to make that object choose between multiple options and how would i invoke it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, I deleted the headers from the object, and now i simply specify them when launching the object

```
 API.post(constants.urlBackend + "/register", qs.stringify({ email, password }), {
            'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8'
        }).
```